# SSH Service Status

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am checking the status of the SSH service by typing;

```
sudo service ssh status
```

I got the following output;

```
ssh start/running, process 889
```

Does this mean SSH status is okay. If not what should the output be if the status is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see more output (info) you could `tail` the syslog directly when you restart the `ssh` service like this:

```
sudo service ssh restart; tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

If the `ssh` service is **not OK** then you'll see something like this with exit codes, status etc:

```
Jun  2 10:57:03 xfce systemd[1]: ssh.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jun  2 10:57:03 xfce systemd[1]: Unit ssh.service entered failed state.
Jun  2 10:57:03 xfce systemd[1]: ssh.service failed.
Jun  2 10:57:03 xfce systemd[1]: ssh.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jun  2 10:57:03 xfce systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for ssh.service
Jun  2 10:57:03 xfce systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

But if it **is OK** then:

```
Jun  2 10:57:31 xfce systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jun  2 10:57:31 xfce systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a service is running, use /sbin/service

```
$ sudo service sshd status
openssh-daemon (pid  6258) is running...
$ sudo service sshd stop
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
$ sudo service sshd status
openssh-daemon is stopped
$ sudo service sshd start
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
$ sudo service sshd status
openssh-daemon (pid  1447) is running...
$
```

In your specific case, SSHD is running, PID is 889. Try a `ps aux | grep 889`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Would have marked it as correct but Svan got in there first. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it means the service *should* be OK.

Do you have a reason to suspect it's not OK?

Comment: Thanks for that. Just couldn't find any reference to what output to expect when checking status. I'm having difficulty with a ssh tunnel connection so going through all the necessary to try to sort it.